# GXT Window is there a onblur event

Tags: java, window, gxt

I am using GXT window to create a popup edit window for editing a form field. As I edit the text field, the form field also changes. But I want to capture when the user has clicked outside of the window. That is, I want to capture blur event on a window, is that possible?

Here is a sample of my code for the window:

```
final Window window = new Window();  
    window.setSize(450, 100);  
    window.setPlain(true);  
    window.setModal(true);  
    window.setBlinkModal(true);  
    window.setHeading("Edit Text");  
    window.setLayout(new FitLayout());
    window.setIconStyle("icon-edit");

window.addWindowListener(new WindowListener() {
        public void windowHide(WindowEvent wevent) {
            //do something
        }
    });
```

Can anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This will work for GXT3.  GXT2 seems to have the same window.addDomHandler api though so may work in that version as well.

I threw in the MouseOutHandler version too just in case you decide the user shouldn't have to click... Anyway choose your favorite!

```
window.addDomHandler(new BlurHandler() {

    @Override public void onBlur(BlurEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}, BlurEvent.getType());


window.addDomHandler(new MouseOutHandler() {

    @Override public void onMouseOut(MouseOutEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}, MouseOutEvent.getType());
```

By the way, when adding a DomHandler you don't need to sink the event.

Comment: @beebris You should mark it as correct if it is so people will easily know it is the solution. (shouldn't you?)

Comment: I didn't end up using the solution as they wanted another fix to the problem. Hence I didn't mark it as correct since I haven't tried it.